# could not show/hide a single button in a list

Tags: angular, ionic2

i have a list of audio files and every file have a play and pause button on it, i used ngIf to show or hide that button. but if i click on that button it changes state of all button in that list

```
 <button  class="lowerCase" ion-button (click)="ListAudioFiles()">Audio list</button>

 <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let file of MyAudioFiles" >
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col width-20 >  
                    <ion-icon *ngIf="status" name="play" (click)="startPlayback(file)" ></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon *ngIf="!status" name="square" (click)="stopPlayback(file)" ></ion-icon>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col width-80>{{file.name}}</ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
MyAudioFiles: any[];
constructor() {     }


/*MYfolder represents a folder inside internal memory of my mobile, allFiles gets the collection of all files inside that specific folder, you can think like we have a list of music files inside MYfolder*/


ListAudioFiles(){
        File.listDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'MYfolder /Audios').then(
          (allFiles) => {
            // do something
            console.log("we have audio files", allFiles);
            this.MyAudioFiles = allFiles;
          }
        ).catch(
          (err) => {
            // do something
            console.log("file listing err", err)
          });
    }
```

What i need is if i click on the 1st play button that button alone should be changed to stop, not all button

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following AngularFrance's answer and comments you don't have to "assign" status to your files, you could save then along with your files in your object.

How is the response of your `File.listDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'Vanan/Audios')`method? Ir probably returns an object or array, cause you can use a `*ngFor` in it.

So you can do this:

```
File.listDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'Vanan/Audios').then(
  (allFiles) => {
  // do something
    for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++){ // iterate through your object and save the audio file along with an status
      this.MyAudioFiles.push({
       audio: allFiles[i],
       status: false
      });
    }
  });
```

and in your html

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let file of MyAudioFiles; let i = index"> //get the index of the object's current row
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col width-20 >  
                <ion-icon *ngIf="file.status" name="play" (click)="startPlayback(file.audio, i)" ></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon *ngIf="!file.status" name="square" (click)="stopPlayback(file.audio, i)" ></ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col width-80>{{file.name}}</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

and in your `startPlayback/stopPlayback` methods

```
startPlayback(audio, i){
  this.MyAudioFiles[i].status = true;
  // play audio
}
stopPlayback(audio, i){
  this.MyAudioFiles[i].status = false;
  // stop audio
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: what should i add here "audio: allFiles[i].TheAudioFileItReturns," @Gabriel Wabiz

Comment: The URL of the audio file or something like this. If you update your question and show what `allFiles` returns i can update my answer to help you better

Comment: consider that we have a list of music files inside that MYfolder

Comment: Ok so use the music file, if it comes in a list/object/array then you can push it into another list to do as my example shows. But the case is, you need to iterate your list to get every music file.

Comment: (allFiles)  returns the list of all music items in MYfolder @Gabriel Wabiz

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan so if it's a list you still can iterate through it to get the right file and save a itatus for it in a object, edited my answer so you can see

Comment: getting error "could not push of undefined" in my console i have we have audio files 
[FileEntry, FileEntry, FileEntry]

file listing err TypeError {}

Comment: initialize the variable you want to push in the top of your coce. Let's say you want to push to `MyAudios`, declare it like `MyAudios: any[] = [];` this should do the trick.

Comment: i tried it works good but i could not get my {{file.name}} in html i get err "name of undefined" @Gabriel Wabiz

Comment: Could u answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522864/stop-play-back-of-audio-recorder @Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're binding to a SINGLE `status` property for ALL files.

Could you set up your model so that each file has its own `status` property?

For instance:

```ts
this.MyAudioFiles = [
  { name: 'file1.mp3', status: false },
  { name: 'file2.mp3', status: false },
  // ...
];
```

Or, if you want to store statuses separately from the filenames, you can created a new property for that:

```ts
// This is a new property to store the statuses.
// Each status is keyed by filename so it can be accessed easily.
this.statuses = {
  { 'file1.mp3': false },
  { 'file2.mp3': false },
  // ...
};
```

And in the template:

```html
<!-- Option #1 - Storing the statuses along with the filenames -->
<ion-item *ngFor="let file of MyAudioFiles">
  <ion-icon *ngIf="file.status" name="play" (click)="startPlayback(file.name)" ></ion-icon>
</ion-item>

<!-- Option #2 - Storing the statuses in a separate property -->
<ion-item *ngFor="let file of MyAudioFiles">
  <ion-icon *ngIf="statuses[file]" name="play" (click)="startPlayback(file)" ></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: i am designing a recorder app i dont think i could assign status to all files. recorded audio will be stored to a folder in mobile and on listing files all files will be listed to view

Comment: I'm not saying that you should modify the model on the server, only that you need a way to store the status **per file**. If you're more comfortable storing statuses *in a separate property* that exists *only in the component*, you can do that too. See updated answer.